# Load specific values from a XML into another XML

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I need to get the value: "SONGTITLE" and seperate it in 2 by the "-".

---

> Blockquote

```
<SHOUTCASTSERVER>
<CURRENTLISTENERS>2</CURRENTLISTENERS>
<PEAKLISTENERS>6</PEAKLISTENERS>
<MAXLISTENERS>5000</MAXLISTENERS>
<UNIQUELISTENERS>2</UNIQUELISTENERS>
<AVERAGETIME>1574</AVERAGETIME>
<SERVERGENRE>Other</SERVERGENRE>
<SERVERGENRE2/>
<SERVERGENRE3/>
<SERVERGENRE4/>
<SERVERGENRE5/>
<SERVERURL>https://ww.reyfm.de</SERVERURL>
<SERVERTITLE>ReyFM | Top100</SERVERTITLE>
<SONGTITLE>
Calvin Harris - Feels (feat. Pharrell Williams, Katy Perry & Big Sean)
</SONGTITLE>
<SONGURL>DNAS/playingart?sid=1</SONGURL>
<STREAMHITS>237</STREAMHITS>
<STREAMSTATUS>1</STREAMSTATUS>
<BACKUPSTATUS>0</BACKUPSTATUS>
<STREAMLISTED>0</STREAMLISTED>
<STREAMLISTEDERROR>200</STREAMLISTEDERROR>
<STREAMSOURCE>109.230.253.249</STREAMSOURCE>
<STREAMPATH>/</STREAMPATH>
<STREAMUPTIME>13511</STREAMUPTIME>
<BITRATE>320</BITRATE>
<CONTENT>audio/mpeg</CONTENT>
<VERSION>2.4.7.256 (posix(linux x64))</VERSION>
</SHOUTCASTSERVER>
```

Then i need to put then in another XML File: The first one goes into "artist" and the second one goes into "title". Example:

> Blockquote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<allchannels count="1">
<ilr_trackinfo channel="1"> 
<artist>
<![CDATA[ Post Malone ]]>
</artist>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Congratulations (feat. Quavo) ]]>
</title> 
<image src="http://95.154.254.129:17618/playingart?sid=1"/>
</ilr_trackinfo>
</allchannels>
```

"ilr_trackinfo channel="1"", "allchannels count="1"", "image" are static.
Is this possible?

---

Help would be much appreciated :)

Image explanation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnpYG.png

Comment: the question is not very clear, but this seems a job for xslt. You can do it in PHP or in javascript. Some details would help

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: what are your options: javascript, php, ... in which language have you tried something...

Comment: You have an invalid xml file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/1461181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<?php

$songs = [];

$channels = range(1,3);

// Download current songs (from 1 to 3)
foreach ($channels as $sid) {
    $song = file_get_contents(sprintf('http://95.154.254.129:17618/currentsong?sid=%s', $sid));
    list($artist, $title) = explode('-', $song, 2);
    $songs[] = [
        'sid' => $sid,
        'image' => sprintf('http://95.154.254.129:17618/playingart?sid=%s', $sid),
        'song' => $song,
        'artist' => trim($artist),
        'title' => trim($title)
    ];
}
unset($song);
//print_r($songs);

// Write new xml file
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$allChannels = $doc->createElement("allchannels");
$allChannels->setAttribute('count' , count($channels));
$doc->appendChild($allChannels);

$trackInfo = $doc->createElement("ilr_trackinfo");
$trackInfo->setAttribute('channel' , $song['sid']);

foreach ($songs as $song) {
    $trackInfo = $doc->createElement("ilr_trackinfo");
    $trackInfo->setAttribute('channel' , $song['sid']);
    $allChannels->appendChild($trackInfo);

    $artist = $doc->createElement("artist");
    $trackInfo->appendChild($artist);

    $artistCdata = $doc->createCDATASection($song['artist']);
    $artist->appendChild($artistCdata);

    $title = $doc->createElement("title");
    $trackInfo->appendChild($title);

    $titleCdata = $doc->createCDATASection($song['title']);
    $title->appendChild($titleCdata);

    $image = $doc->createElement("image");
    $image->setAttribute('src', $song['image']);
    $trackInfo->appendChild($image);
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: I found out that i can get it like this: http://95.154.254.129:17618/currentsong?sid=1

But my problem is that i dont know how to import that into a new xml file that has the format as showed above.

Comment: Could you make the allchannels count="6" get by the URL?

Like so: http://server.de/xmlparser.php?allchannels=6&r=57860
And add a Random String at the end of the Image Src.
And also set the image Src to "http://www.reyfm.de/img/nocover.png" if no Image is available? This would Fix all my Problems :)

Comment: How can i get to display the XML when i view the php in my browser?
Like: http://www.iloveradio.de/xmlparser.php?allchannels=207&r=57860

Comment: Just add the correct header: header("Content-type: text/xml");

Comment: From my point of view the original question has already been answered.

Comment: Here is my new Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460207/php-xml-adding-a-random-string-to-a-image-src-and-replace-image-src-with-anot

Comment: Could you help me on my other question?